# toggleDown jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you hover over the arrow it should toggle the footer down so you can see its content. When the mouse is inside the `#footer` the div should remain opened so you can read the content.

The problem is when you hover on the arrow the div just opens and closes.

here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MEJgb/1/

Comment: In the fiddle when I'm hover the arrow and animate the body to scroll I lose the over on arraw and the animation never stop. So if you add .stop() `.offset().top}, 'slow').stop();` to the end of body animation this could do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

try changing this line

```
jQuery(this).next("#footer_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
```

to

```
jQuery(this).next("#footer_toggle").stop().slideToggle("slow");
```

Or try something like this I guess if I understand your question right

http://jsfiddle.net/MEJgb/21/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hover event use click event for this

```
jQuery("#toggleDiv").click(function() {});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MEJgb/12/) is here!!

I hope it will works..

Comment: i dont want click!, it used to be click - i removed it - i want hover

Comment: because of, on the mouse hover div will appear and mouse position will be lost. This is the problem behind the seen. If you want to remove this than you have use this click event.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // footer Toggle        
    $("#footer_toggle").hide();

    $("#toggleDiv").click(function() {
        $("#footer_toggle").slideToggle();
        if($("#toggleDiv").hasClass('active'))
            $("#toggleDiv").removeClass("active");
        else
        $("#toggleDiv").addClass("active");
    });
});
```